# Nav Pills data is not collapsing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am able to collapse the links of default navbar but I do not want to use default navbar. I want to have nav pills and the links under pills should be collapsed for smaller screens. My nav pills data is not collapsing for smaller screens. Here is my code:

```
<div class = "row">
    <nav class = "navbar" role = "navigation">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "navbar-header">
                <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#collapse">
                    <span class = "sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class = "navbar-brand inline" href = "#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class = "img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "collapse">
                <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your code put this in instead of the code following:

`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>`

That code replaces this:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

`

Comment: This is for navbar menu but it don't work on navbar pills. I have already mentioned this in my question.